# java applet reports SocketException or ConnectException but connection is OK

Tags: java, networking, applet, connectivity

I'm somewhat new to java applet programming and am maintaining someone else's applet.  The signed applet records some voice and then uploads the file.  In the upload, we sometimes get one of these exceptions(SocketException, ConnectException, even UnknownHostException).  We trap them, and then report them via a Javascript call from the applet.  The javascript call runs fine, which to me indicates that the connection is OK.  How can it be that the applet can't open a socket or can't connect but there are no issues w/ the browser connecting?

Clarification: What I meant by "connection is OK" is that the network and server are both fine, so I'm not sure why the applet can't establish the connection.

The applet is signed and does have network access.  This happens very occasionally.

Thanks

Comment: Does the JavaScript report the entire stack trace? If not, change it so that it does. Knowing that you have an exception is useless unless you know where it happened. And if you do have the stack trace, please post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in the browser and it uses a connection of its own if it engages with the server. So that's irrelevant. If the applet got a ConnectException there *is no connection* to be OK, and if you get *any* IOException other than SocketTimeoutException the connection is hosed and *not* OK, no two ways about it, and nothing you can do except close the socket and start again.

Comment: Thanks.  What I meant by "connection is OK" is that the network and server are both fine, so I'm not sure why the applet can't establish the connection.  I'm not too familiar with the networking stack - what would cause a connection failure for the applet while the browser has no such issues?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information its hard to tell what the specific problem is here.
If that really only happens very occasionally and in the next call (that from JavaScript) it works fine, it could help to just try it twice to establish the connection.

```
Socket con;
try {
    con.connect(...);
} catch (IOException ignoreFirstFailure) {
    try {
        con.connect(...);
    } catch (IOExcetpion secondFailure) {
        handleExceptionWithJavaScript(secondFailure);
    }
}
```

So, for further information it would be really helpful if you would state what kind of connection you are using and how.